# Did early Russian capsules really have "Human Inside" labels?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, history, russia

[This comic](http://satwcomic.com/space-attack) claims that it was to prevent people panicking and attacking the crew. However, Vostok pilots were supposed to land separately from the capsule. Are there any photos supporting this claim? Which ships used such label?

Comment: In the early days of the space program there were a lot of pretty primitive groups around that would have no idea of what had just come crashing down.  Such a label makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the Soyuz TM-10 capsule had such a label next to the exterior hatch, according to [The Bloc on the Block](http://discovermagazine.com/1994/apr/thebloconthebloc363) by Jeffrey Kluger in the April 1994 issue of Discover Magazine:

> Then there were lots 154 and 175, the Kosmos 1443 and Soyuz TM-10 space capsules. Sotheby's hoped to get top dollar for these artifacts, and the catalog included photographs of some of the ships' more interesting details in an effort to spark the bidding. (One photo showed the message stenciled in Russian and English next to the Soyuz's exterior hatch, in case the spacecraft was found by a passerby before recovery teams could reach it: MAN INSIDE! HELP! OPEN THE HATCH! TAKE THE KEY! PUT INTO THE HOLE!)

There is a picture [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/vruba/12080725555), for those interested. (I won't be including the picture in the post due to copyright restrictions.)

Comment: why only Russian had this?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch It just so happens that NASA had something like this as well on the Apollo command module: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32449/58